# bash while loop and ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, while-loop

Sorry for this questions I imagine the answer is pretty straightforward however I have had a search and I haven't found anything that answers it.

I have written the following:

```
while read p                        # reads in each line of the text
do                                  # file- folder_list.txt each iteration.
    echo "$p"                       # print out current line
    if [ -f  $p/frame_number1.jpg ] # checks if the image exists in the specific folder
    then
        echo "$p"                   #prints specific folder name
        sleep 1                     #pause for 1 second
        ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10 -i $p/frame_number%01d.jpg -r 30 $p/out.mp4  #create video
     fi                             # end if statement
done <folder_list.txt               #end of while loop
```

The script is supposed to read a text file which contains the folder tree structure, then check if the folder contains the specified JPEG if it does then the code should create a video from the images contained within the specified folder.

However what appears to be happening is the script skips whole folders that definitely contain images. I was wondering if the while loop is continuing to iterate whilst the video is being created or if something else is happening?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Laurence

Comment: you are missing to use `"` around variables consequently.

Comment: thanks it appears to work either way.

Comment: any sudo problem? If it skips some folders and not others... try to run your script with sudo

Comment: just tried under sudo and doesn't apear to be, although it is very random

Comment: I have found the problem. Within some of the folders there was already an .mp4 file which had previously been created and for some reason this was having an impact on the iteration. The way that I solved this was to add the yes instruction i.e.:

    yes y | ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10 -i $p/frame_number%01d.jpg -r 30 $p/out.mp4  #create video from images

thanks for taking the time to comment.

Comment: @Larry_b This tells you the need to add debug output and tests to your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because some folders contain spaces, or other weird characters.

Try this (won't work for ALL but for MOST cases):

```
while read p            # reads in each line of the text file- folder_list.txt
do                      #each iteration
   echo "$p"               #print out current line
   if [  -f   "${p}/frame_number1.jpg"  ] #checks wether the image exists in the specific folder
   then echo "$p"      #printsout specific folder name
        sleep 1                 #pause for 1 second
        ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10 -i "${p}/frame_number%01d.jpg" -r 30 "${p}/out.mp4"  #create video
   fi                  # end if statement
done <folder_list.txt   #end of while loop
```

I just added quotes around arguments involving "$p" so that if it contains space (and other things) it's not separated into several arguments, breaking the command

If this doesn't work, tell us exactly a few of the directories that are OK and the ones that are NOT ok :

```
ls -ald  /some/ok/dir     /some/NOTOK/dir #will show which directories belong to who
id  #will tell us which user you are using, so we can compare to the previous and find out why you can't access some
```